# Fedora 25 is so slow to Boot

Tags: linux, boot, performance, fedora

I have a Fedora 25 running the latest updated Kernel.

The problem is that Fedora takes near 3mins to Boot.

Here is the output of `systemd-analyse`

```
Startup finished in 4.075s (kernel) + 3.580s (initrd) + 3min 19.186s (userspace) = 3min 26.841s
```

Here is the Output of `systemd-analyse blame`

```
3min 124ms abrtd.service
         29.022s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         10.230s libvirtd.service
         10.216s firewalld.service
         10.123s lvm2-monitor.service
          9.486s systemd-journald.service
          8.749s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          8.394s systemd-udev-settle.service
          8.051s dev-mapper-fedora\x2droot.device
          7.263s dnf-makecache.service
          5.738s packagekit.service
          5.239s lvm2-pvscan@8:4.service
          4.933s accounts-daemon.service
          2.914s mnt-Personal.mount
          2.630s ModemManager.service
          2.440s proc-fs-nfsd.mount
          2.440s cups.service
          2.112s systemd-journal-flush.service
          2.067s gssproxy.service
          1.988s polkit.service
          1.982s fedora-readonly.service
          1.795s systemd-binfmt.service
          1.661s systemd-udevd.service
          1.598s livesys.service
          1.598s switcheroo-control.service
          1.514s systemd-logind.service
          1.475s NetworkManager.service
          1.428s swapfile.swap
          1.340s proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
          1.333s auditd.service
          1.226s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
           940ms rtkit-daemon.service
           938ms bluetooth.service
           897ms rpc-statd-notify.service
           845ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
           763ms wpa_supplicant.service
           760ms chronyd.service
           741ms systemd-sysctl.service
           691ms user@1000.service
           661ms gdm.service
           610ms colord.service
           580ms tlp.service
```

I think `abrtd.service` is the culprit here. My `gnome-abrt` reports that there are near 3000 issues on my Computer and the latest one is about 2 months old.

How do I fix this.

P.S: Please say what other outputs that I need to include.

Comment: The whole point of gnome-abrtd is to report problems with the system. Have you begun working through some of the problems to try to solve them?

Comment: I know, But the problems listed are 2 months old, I just want Fedora to boot faster. https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/87445/abrt-takes-many-seconds-to-load-on-boot/ . I think this is my Issue.

Comment: Then have you followed the steps outlined on that post?

Comment: Nop. How do I clear abrt cache directory ?

Comment: Also if it helps, when I shutdown a black screen with a message saying ` A start Job for abrt is currently running` and then waits for a few seconds and then shows the Fedora Logo and shutdown

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do is to stop and disable the `abrt` service to see if that reduces the system boot time to an acceptable value.

```
# systemctl stop abrtd.service
# systemctl disable abrtd.service
```

Comment: Alright that brings boot time down to 1 min